# Maven package versions in final deployment

Tags: java, maven

It is known that whenever a search is done through the Maven repository, one can find dependencies for different versions of a package (e.g. [BoneCP Maven Search](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.jolbox%22%20AND%20a%3a%22bonecp%22)) depending on the [Development Stage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_stage#Beta).

I would like to know, for any **external dependency** found in the [Maven](http://search.maven.org/#browse) repository, **which version should be included in a final deployment of a project**. For instance:

- Always the latest RELEASE/RC (Release Candidate)?
- Always the latest version even if its an alpha/beta/SNAPSHOT version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a release you generally create a tag from stable snapshot version [trunk] and then deploy it to repository.

Generally the highest tag version for the each release is taken for code release and deployment.

Also want to add snapshot version is meant for development and not for release.

Comment: Are RC (Release candidates) packages also considered as 'highest tag version for the each release'? I want to know about external dependencies, not my own project.

Comment: By external you mean 3rd party or from other project?

Comment: I am referring to versions of packages found in Maven repo. Please, have a look at [this] (http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.jolbox%22%20AND%20a%3A%22bonecp%22) example.

Comment: For bonecp, looking at the versions in list, i will go with version ending with .release i.e 0.7.1.release. It will depend upon vendor what kind of naming convention it will follow.

Comment: So, the latest RELEASE version, NOT the RC/Alpha/Beta/SNAPSHOT, etc...Surely, it will depend on the vendor naming convention. Thanks.